# Do I get anything for filling the Photo Album?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

There is a photo album that chronicles my journey, inside the camera shop.

Apparently I need 12 pictures to fill it.

Do I get anything for filling the album with pictures (other than a whole bunch of pictures that I can't print because this is a Virtual Console title so I can't hook up a GameBoy Printer even if I had one)?

Comment: Only if you have a Game Boy printer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no reward as far as I know.  The [Zelda Wiki](http://www.zeldawiki.org/Photo_Album) doesn't mention one either, although it does say that it's possible to miss some of them, and there are a total of 13 possible (although you can only get 12 maximum).